# VB.NET match string between same characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'll have to read a regex tutorial - so far I have a mental block in this area - right now I am just trying to match the following pattern:

```
ab234_12345_45678_afddsyyht788959
```

I am trying to extract the third (likely numeric) item surrounded by underscores (if the string has the wrong pattern, return invalid format, of course).

Something like:

```
Dim strOriginal As String = "ab234_12345_45678_afddsyyht788959"
Dim strFound As String
Try
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim regexStuff As New Regex("_.*?_")
    matches = regexStuff.Matches(strOriginal)
    strFound = matches.Item(0).Groups(2).Value.ToString
Catch
    strFound = "invalid"
End Try
MessageBox.Show(strFound)
```

The problem is with the pattern - I can't figure out anything that works... (I have tried a few other patterns too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Match the `\1` group

If you want the third group to be numeric replace `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` with `(\d+)`